# Did Democritus predict atoms using Sharp Phase Transitions? How? Couldn't a classical field theory also have Sharp Phase Transitions?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, history, classical-field-theory, critical-phenomena

In the [Wikipedia page for the Ising Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model) it is written without citations:

> One of Democritus' arguments in support of atomism was that atoms naturally explain the sharp phase boundaries observed in materials[citation needed], as when ice melts to water or water turns to steam.

My question is:

Is this statement historically accurate? If so, did Democritus have an argument or explained his intuition on how exactly atoms explain sharp phase transitions?

A related question, would be how this relates to a a modern statistical mechanics viewpoint and If one really needs an atomistic description:

From a continuous model of matter like a classical field theory, could one arrive at a first order phase transition from first principles? I know you could just 'artificially' impose a phase transition, but I'm thinking of a procedure like taking the large-scale limit of a classical field theory and arriving at a new theory with phase transitions.

Comment: Maybe try: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am not sure about hsm. He isn't asking about what Democritus thought so much as "Are sharp phase transitions truly evidence of atoms?" That is a physics question.

Comment: The [Landay theory of phase transitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_theory) can deal with both continuous and discontinuous phase transitions and is based on a classical field (the order parameter). Maybe you can find some interesting reference here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/409610/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/733174/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/661194/226902